# Passar classe mysql para mysqli erro na consulta

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou com um problema para passar a consulta `(this->Query($sql))` e os demais para `mysqli`. Não sei como proceder

**ERROS:**

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null
>   given in /var/www/html/manager/include/class.mysqldb.php on line 23
>   PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, null given in
>   /var/www/html/manager/include/class.mysqldb.php on line 27 PHP
>   Warning:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in /var/www/html/manager/include/class.mysqldb.php on line
>   31

```
<?php
class mysqldb {
    var $link;
    var $result;
    function connect($config) {
        $this->link = mysqli_connect($config['hostname'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['database']);
        if ($this->link) {
            mysqli_query($this->link, "SET NAMES 'utf-8'");
            return true;
        }
        $this->show_error(mysqli_error($this->link), "connect()");
        return false;
    }
    function selectdb($database) {
        if ($this->link) {
            mysqli_select_db($this->link, $database);
            return true;
        }
        $this->show_error("Not connect the database before", "selectdb($database)");
        return false;
    }
    function query($sql) {
        $this->query = mysqli_query($this->link, $sql);
        return $this->query;
    }
    function fetch() {
        $result = mysqli_fetch_object($this->query);
        return $result;
    }
    function num_rows() {
        return mysqli_num_rows($this->query);
    }
    function show_error($errmsg, $func) {
        echo "<b><font color=red>" . $func . "</font></b> : " . $errmsg . "<BR>\n";
        exit(1);
    }
}
?>
```

Como chamo a classe

```
<?php
# configuration for database
$_config['database']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$_config['database']['username'] = "root";
$_config['database']['password'] = "senha";
$_config['database']['database'] = "banco";

# connect the database server
$link = new mysqldb();
$link->connect($_config['database']);
$link->selectdb($_config['database']['database']);
$link->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

@session_start();
```

?>

Comment: Seria interessante ter algum dos erros que acontecem para que possamos partir daí. Assim vai ficar amis fácil entender cada erro e trazer uma solução.

Comment: Tens Razão, aqui os erros que acontecem
 PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/html/manager/include/class.mysqldb.php on line 23
PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /var/www/html/manager/include/class.mysqldb.php on line 27
PHP Warning:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /var/www/html/manager/include/class.mysqldb.php on line 31 @ErlonCharles

Comment: Coloca o código de como vc chama essa classe.

Comment: @rray
`
<?php
 # configuration for database
 $_config['database']['hostname'] = "localhost";
 $_config['database']['username'] = "root";
 $_config['database']['password'] = "xxx";
 $_config['database']['database'] = "banco";
 
 # connect the database server
 $link = new mysqldb();
 $link->connect($_config['database']);
 $link->selectdb($_config['database']['database']);
 $link->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
 
 @session_start();
?>`

Comment: @rray, usava desta forma no php5, aqui localmente, nao tinha problema, o que queria é colocar num servidor aqui do outro lado que usau php7 ai precisava migrar as strings mysql para mysqli, é ai que ocorre os problemas, nos erros a conexão parece tá ok só a consulta que da erro, mas tambem nao manjo pra confirmar

Comment: Faça o seguinte: mude: `$this->query = mysqli_query($this->link, $sql);` para `$this->query = mysqli_query($this->link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($this->link));` veja se aparece outra mensagem de erro.

Comment: @rray agora fica em branco a tela sem acusar qualquer tipo de erro, no log do apache continua mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Comment: Então a conexão não é válida, verifique isso, veja o retorno de `connect()`

Comment: @rray como? return connect(); ? assim deu erro. não manjo muito ><

Answer (score 0):

Cara creio que o problema esteja no seu arquivo de configuração que conecta com o banco que ainda está no modelo antigo.

```
$link = new mysqldb();
```

Tenta dessa forma aqui abaixo com o mysqli, sempre uso e nunca tive problema com versões PHP:

```
$link = new mysqli('localhost', $_USER, $_PASS, $_DB);
 $link->set_charset("utf8");

if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error()); }

mysqli_query($link,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($link,"SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysqli_query($link,"SET CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION=utf8");
mysqli_query($link,"SET SQL_MODE = ''");
```

Comment: mesmo erro mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in
mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Comment: @Weliton testei aqui com o trecho que falei e funcionou. Percebi que vc esqueceu o de declarar var $query; na classe mysqldb. Verifica se é isso.